# Adding sub project dependency in gradle works weirdly, IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a gradle multi project.
'root' has 2 sub projects which named 'domain' and 'web'. 'web' needs to use classes which are declared in 'domain' project.

However whenever I add `compile project(':domain')` into dependencies of 'web'.

Intellij says 'root_main', 'root_test', 'web_main', 'web_test' are not imported from Gradle anymore, which I don't want to.

Could you tell me how I can add dependency 'domain' into 'web'?

The structure is below :

```
root
├── build.gradle
├── domain
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│       └── test
│               
├── web
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│       └── test
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

'build.gradle' in root

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    group = 'com.sample.projects.multi'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }
}
```

'build.gradle' in domain

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
}
```

'build.gradle' in web

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ppl who might have same issue with me, I resolved this by updating Intellij to newer one. Mine was 2017.1 and I updated it to 2018.1.